# Node express router and typescript route for put doesn't run as expected

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Newbie with node and express, i'm stuck with a strange problem with express routing.

In a router file, i define some routes (simplified for purpose) :

```
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { AccountController } from './../controllers/account-controller';

const accountController: AccountController = new AccountController();

export class AccountRouter {
    public router: Router;

    /**
     * Instanciation du contrôleur pour les comptes
     */
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();

        this._init();
    }

    private _init(): void {
        // Requête de contrôle d'existence
            .get(
                '/:username',
                this._check
            )
            // Ajout d'un compte
            .post(
                '/',
                this._add
            )

            // Mise à jour d'un compte
            .put(
                '/:mongoId',
                this._update
            )
    }

    /**
     * Check for a user
     * @param request 
     * @param response 
     * @param next 
     */
    private _check(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        accountController.check(request, response, next);
    }

    /**
     * add an account
     * @param request 
     * @param response 
     * @param next 
     */
    private _add(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {

        accountController.add(request, response, next);
    }

    private _update(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) 
{
        accountController.update(request, response, next);
    }
}

const accountRoutes = new AccountRouter();
export default accountRoutes.router;
```

Firsts routes work as expected, validate them with Postman, but... route for put returns a 404 http error...

When i try to touch the put route from a client, have first an OPTION with a 204 then a 404 for the put himself.

The update() method is defined in the model...

In app.ts (entry of the app...) :

```
    // Routes pour la gestion des comptes
    AccountRouter.use(cors(corsOptions));
    this.app.use('/api/v2/account', AccountRouter);
```

And cors options are :

```
const corsOptions: cors.CorsOptions = {
    allowedHeaders: ["Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "X-Access-Token"],
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    origin: '*',
    preflightContinue: false
}
```

I can't understand why this specific route returns a 404 when the others run as expected.

Thx 4 help